# Unable to hold Volley response value for further use, it turns null

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I was just experimenting with Volley to learn network call. I found this rather strange so I just want to why this happens. The [android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) had similar example for Volley and I changed a little bit so that the response is held in the string `responseJSON` and I use that to set it to a textView in the activity. When I set the textView **within** the `onResponse()` function, the result is displayed in the textview(commented line) but if I do it **outside** the function like shown below the `responseJSON` string turns `null`(I checked via toast) and so the textView appears blank. Why does this happen? Why doesn't `responseJSON` simply bind to response, scope is still valid so unable to understand why this happens.

```
package com.example.imnobody.sampleprojectnetwork;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String reponseJSON;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="https://www.google.com";



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        reponseJSON = response;
                        //mTextView.setText(reponseJSON);


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);

        mTextView.setText(reponseJSON);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have internet permission **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />** in mainfest..?

Comment: As I said I have no problem when I have mTextView.setText(reponseJSON) within onResponse method, only when it's outside there's no result and I want to know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onCreate` method `mTextView.setText(reponseJSON);` you are just setting the text to the textview, you are not setting the reponseJSON object reference,

And your `StringRequest` is an asynchronous request, the response will come little later, once you got the response you will set into `reponseJSON` object. if you want to udpate the value to the text view you should set again the text value.

Comment: Oh okay, so if I set the response within onResponse(), I'm basically setting it after I received the response so it displays the output, but in the above case I'm setting it before I receive a response and so it's null?